# How to run an exe by client remotely on server using vb6

Tags: vb6, cmd, exe, remote-access

I'm using code below to execute my commands in cmd. Which is actually made for running an exe on my server.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim FN As Integer
    FN = FreeFile
    'DOS COMMANDS
    ServerName = "\\mydbserv"
    ExePath = """d:\myfolder\my.exe"""
    UserName = "myserver\myuser"
    Password = "mypass"
    MyCommand = "psexec " & ServerName & " -u " & UserName & " -p " & Password & " -i " & ExePath
    'Open Bat file
    Open "C:\Mybatc.bat" For Output As #FN
        Print #FN, "cd c:\Users\myuser"
        Print #FN, MyCommand
        Print #FN, "Exit"
    Close #FN
    'Activate
    result = Shell("C:\Mybatc.bat", vbHide)
    End
End Sub
```

everything was fine until i seen that cmd is not getting closed when process is done.
and the worse is the exe i was trying to run remotely also not stops. When i check the cpu usage it always shows "00" doesnt even starts.. It shows like working for ever but never works actually.
So my question is :

1. Why i cant run this exe file remotely? (or why it just shows like running)
2. How can i remotely run and close when finished this exe file on server?
3. How can i close the window and process when finished on my pc as well?

Comment: Just because it's using 0% CPU, it doesn't mean it "doesn't even start". Does it work when you run the batch file from the command prompt? `my.exe` could be waiting for some input, etc.

Comment: @Deanna when i start the exe manually it tooks less than 1 second to start but when i do it with psexec it doesnt even shows the form so what ever its waiting for i dont know but i want it to execute right in time it can take more than 1 sec its no problem but it shouldnt take hours to start.. that only shows there is an error somewhere..

Comment: @BerkerYüceer : what happens when you start the psexec command from the command prompt ? (not from within vb) do you get any results or error messages ? ... maybe your syntax of the psexec command is incorrect ?

Comment: Are you expecting windows to appear on your local system?  That's just not going to happen. That's why I suggested running the batch file (and in turn, psexec) directly.

Comment: @Deanna u misunderstood me im talking about server side it doesnt show up at serverside it seems like working but shows the cpu usage 00 and shows the memory usage static at 2,854 doesnt changes a bit.. and also Hrqls at client side on cmd it just waits, doesnt gives any errors or messages just waits like that for couple hours.. im mostly thinking on the posibility that my psexec command is incorrect.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer : that's my idea as well. does my.exe run when you login on the remote system manually ? i don't know psexec, but had a quick look at the psexec manual : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx .... you might want to try the -d option ?

Comment: Also remember that anything running remotely may not have access to the remote user's desktop session and so no UI will appear on screen. Now you've concluded that the problem is nothing to do with VB, and all in your my.exe and psexec,, can you close and create a new question or edit this one with the new information?

Comment: @Deanna it is about vb6. i wanna remotely start an exe using vb6 i just used psexec cause i couldnt find any other solution yet.. so if you know a way to remotely run an exe in vb6 please share. My only option so far was cmd but i'm open for other solutions.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer : when you can get the psexec running from the command prompt, then you can use it via VB as well .. but when you can't use it from the command prompt, then it won't work from VB either ..... so first try to make your psexec command work from the command prompt, then make it work from within the batch file, then make it work from VB

Comment: @Hrqls ok i'm being misunderstood again and again. It is already working in command prompt but at serverside exe never stops. Just gets stuck on same memory and cpu usage and waits forever like that.
On client side also psexec waits for the program to finish. It doesnt matter if i close the cmd on client side after i initiate the process, cause its never gonna end on server side. I appreciate the help and Deanna i changed the title hope its better now.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer : ah ok, sorry i misunderestood. in that case your problem still isn't in the VB part either, but probably in my.exe being run remotely .... does my.exe run correctly when run locally on the remote machine ? ... what does my.exe do ? does it need administration rights ? does it try to write a file somewhere where it might not have write access ?

Comment: there's a bug in psexec and it does redirects correctly when is called by everything different by cmd. You have few more options to start a process on remote machine: 1. http://feldkir.ch/xcmd.htm - it cannot be run on localhost 2. WMIC - also cannot be used on localhost , when host and and user/pass are given 2. SCHTASKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

1. install Windbg on the server.
2. config the windbg auto attach to your exe, when your exe is ready to running.
   http://ask.brothersoft.com/image-file-execution-options-debugger-83827.html
3. running your script
4. after your exe is started, the windbg will attach to it.
5. input 'g'  in the windbg command, let your exe to running.
6. wait until you think it should finished
7. ctrl-break to let the process hang on
8. input '~*kb' to windbg command, to see what's going on in every thread, 
   to find out why they are waiting, and what they are waiting for?

Answer (score 3):

PSExec will only initiate the start of the process in a computer (most of the time remote), after that it has no control on the exe that is being executed. Kindly try to run it as a process (within a ProcessInfo as in C#)(with shell execute false). Also something like the following can be used to confirm the state of the process in remote PC:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim sReturn As String
    Dim strNameOfUser As Variant
    Dim colProcesses As Object
    Dim objProcess As Object
    strComputer = "." '"." local or "\\ComputerName"
    Set colProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
    For Each objProcess In colProcesses
        sReturn = objProcess.GetOwner(strNameOfUser)
        If sReturn <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Could not get owner info for process " & objProcess.Name & vbNewLine & "Error = " & sReturn
        Else
            MsgBox "Process " & objProcess.Name & " is owned by " & "\" & strNameOfUser & "."
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

link : http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?355203-RESOLVED-How-to-get-process-information
hope it helps

Comment: the problem is i already can see what process runs but its not actually running.. but still this is smt good to know. +1